# Does a +2 weapon affect spell damage?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items

I have a choice between a +2 wand of the war mage and a +2 weapon at the end of White Plume Mountain from *Tales From the Yawning Portal*.

Does a +2 wand/quarterstaff affect spell attack rolls and spell damage? I have not found a specific answer as to whether or not a +X weapon that a sorcerer is proficient with will affect spell attack rolls and spell damage rolls.

Answer (score 19):

#### The Wand increases your to-hit with spell attacks, the weapon increases to-hit and damage rolls with the weapon

A magic item's description will tell you what an item does. Keeping in mind that the DM is allowed to change the powers of magic weapons as they see fit, the following descriptions are the RAW function of the items.

A [Wand of the War Mage +2](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/wand-of-the-war-mage-2) does the following:

> While holding this wand, you gain a +2 bonus to spell attack rolls. In addition, you ignore half cover when making a spell attack.

And a [Weapon +2](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/weapon-2) does the following:

> You have a +2 bonus to attack and damage rolls made with this magic weapon.

So in the case of the wand, your to-hit bonus for spells is increased by 2, but you gain no bonus to spell damage. The +2 weapon provides bonuses only to attack and damage rolls made *with the weapon*. Attacking with a spell is not attacking with the weapon, so holding a +2 weapon will not confer any bonus to your spells unless the item description says otherwise.

As it so happens, I own TFYP and all of the descriptions of unique magic items appear in the back of the book. If an item cannot be found in that appendix, it can be found in the Magic Items section of the DMG.

Comment: Thank you kindly. I had rather assumed as much but wanted someone else's input.